# how to implement custom progress bar

Tags: html, css, progress-bar

I need these background for progress bar. Initially color is thick later it is light color. How to implement this design for progress bar?

```css
.progressOuterBody {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 64px;
  padding: 1px 10px;
}
.progressBarInnerBody {
  width: 25%;
  background: red;
  /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, red, yellow);
  /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(right, red, yellow);
  /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(right, red, yellow);
  /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  border-radius: 45px;
}
```

```html
<div class="progressOuterBody">
  <div class="progressBarInnerBody">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @SumnerEvans Please see my code.I need the background color css.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using bootstrap, you can use their progress bars as well. They're pretty customization.  Read more here: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_progressbars.asp

Comment: i want the background color css for progress bar.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. You want the color of it? Like, you don't know what color that is?

Comment: We can apply only one color.It has two colors in background.

Comment: The bootstrap class .progress-bar-striped should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can add one more `<div>`(`.shade`) inside the `progressBarInnerBody`. `.shade` will cover your entire inner div and afterwards, add linear-gradient to that `.shade`.

**Update**:

- Added stripes from your fiddle

Issue in your fiddle is:

- You should have added stripes in `progressBarInnerBody` instead of in `shade`
- You need to provide the `background-size` to `progressBarInnerBody`

Here is the snippet:

```js
function slider_changed(e) {
  $(".progressBarInnerBody").css('width', e.target.value + "%");
}
```

```css
.progressOuterBody {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 64px;
  padding: 3px;
}
.progressBarInnerBody {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  background: dodgerblue;
  /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, dodgerblue, dodgerblue);
  /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(right, dodgerblue, dodgerblue);
  /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(right, dodgerblue, dodgerblue);
  /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  border-radius: 45px;
  background-size: 60px 60px;
  animation: barberpole 0.5s linear infinite;
}
.shade {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), transparent);
  /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), transparent);
  /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), transparent);
  /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  border-radius: 45px;
}
@keyframes barberpole {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 60px 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="progressOuterBody">
    <div class="progressBarInnerBody">
      <div class="shade">

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <input type="range" id="slider" value="80" oninput="slider_changed(event)">

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @gurubuddy did it help?

Comment: it helped but when i am adding the animated stripes css then i am not getting the exacted stripes like  above picture.Could you please  help me?

Comment: @gurubuddy can you share your fiddle? I'll check once.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2wf5m6m4/  . Stripes is not overlay on progressbar. Please help.

Comment: please  find below url of fiddle. Stripes is not overlay on progressbar. Please help.

Comment: Thank you very much